# Como hago para visualizar la imagen

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

me preguntaba el como podría mostrar una imagen en un formulario que muestra información de los campos de una tabla dependiendo de su id , no estoy guardando la imagen en si no la dirección de la carpeta donde tengo guardada la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la quisiera mostrar en el formulario , ya sea con una etiqueta de a de hipervinculo o con la etiqueta img , pero no se el como. Utilizo Ajax para mostrar los campos en el formulario.

```js
  function Tinv(id){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:{'id':id},
    dataType:'json',
    url: uri + "/inventario/mostrarInv",
  }).done(function(respuesta){

    $("#id").val(respuesta.id);
    $("#ubicacioni").val(respuesta.ubicacion);
    $("#asignadoi").val(respuesta.asignado);
    $("#subcategoriai").val(respuesta.subcategoria);
    $("#estadoi").val(respuesta.estado);
    $("#actividadi").val(respuesta.actividad);
    $("#sistemaoi").val(respuesta.sistemao);
    $("#marcai").val(respuesta.marca);
    $("#modeloi").val(respuesta.modelo);
    $("#seriali").val(respuesta.serialp);
    $("#placai").val(respuesta.placa);
    $("#serialcargadori").val(respuesta.serialcargador);
    $("#serialbateriai").val(respuesta.serialbateria);
    $("#velocidadprocesadori").val(respuesta.velocidadprocesador);
    $("#rami").val(respuesta.ram);
    $("#discoduroi").val(respuesta.discoduro);
    $("#ipi").val(respuesta.ip);
    $("#lani").val(respuesta.lan);
    $("#wlani").val(respuesta.wlan);
    $("#activirusi").val(respuesta.antivirus);
    $("#observacionesi").val(respuesta.observaciones);
    $("#licenciaos").val(respuesta.licenciaos);



    $("#modalInv").modal();

  }).fail(function(r){
    alert(r);
  });
}
```

con este código javascript muestro los campos que estan guardados en la base de datos por el id.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces no se como podría mostrar la imagen con la dirección guardada en la base de datos , puesto que muestro la información de cada uno de los campos corresponden a una fila en la bd.

Comment: quisiera saber si lo que quieres es solamente mostrar la imagen dentro del formulario o también que se pueda reemplazar dentro del formulario

Comment: Solo visualizarla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo cambiando el atributo src de un elemento img con jquery de esta forma:

```
<img id="imagen" src="">
```

```
$("#imagen").attr("src", respuesta.licenciaos);
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo , llevaba investigando esto hace rato  y no podía encontrarlo.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de ponerlo asi `$("#licenciaos").val(respuesta.licenciaos);`
, intenta esto..  `$("#licenciaos").src "direccion de ubicacion" + respuesta.licenciados;`

Te dejo esto para que te guies mejor.

```
document.getElementById('imagenEditar').src = "http://localhost/WareHouse/assets/img/" + image;
```